# Is there an Anti-Accio (Anti-Summoning) Charm on the Ministry and Hogwarts Letters?

Tags: harry-potter

Was there anything ever preventing the Death Eaters and Voldemort from summoning the letters that went to and from Hogwarts and to and from the Ministry of Magic in their efforts to overthrow or kill their respective leaders?

It isn't like the British Ministry restricted the use of the Summoning Charm (Accio), nor was it ever stated that the Ministry of Magic was able to trace its usages.

Answer (score 3):

There is no canon information about the letters being Accio-able or not.

But we can see in multiple occasions, that Anti- Accio- charms are very commonly used and expected to be used. Here are some examples:

> She raised her wand and said, “Accio Locket!”
>   Nothing happened. Ron, who had been searching the folds of
>   the faded curtains, looked disappointed.
>   “Is that it, then? It’s not here?”
>   “Oh, it could still be here, but under counter-enchantments,”
>   said Hermione. “Charms to prevent it being summoned magically,
>   you know.”
>   “Like Voldemort put on the stone basin in the cave,” said Harry, remembering
>   how he had been unable to Summon the fake locket.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 10</sub>
>
> He pointed the wand at the silvery shape and murmured, “Accio
>   Sword.”
>   It did not stir. He had not expected it to.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 19</sub>
>
> “Accio Cup!” cried Hermione, who had evidently forgotten in her
>   desperation what Griphook had told them during their planning
>   sessions.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26</sub>

Of course all of these examples are about highly protected items but there is one hint, that the spells are commonly known:

> “Accio Locket.”
>   Nothing happened, but he had not expected it to; **no doubt Umbridge
>   knew all about protective charms and spells**.
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13</sub>

I can imagine, that putting an Anti- Accio- charm on every letter is not unreasonable.

Comment: Odd that locket + Umbridge didn't come soaring up from the courtrooms when Harry tried that _accio_ in the MoM.